# is there any way to prevent grab window to minimize?

Tags: unity, wine, minimize

I've been having this awful issue where if I grab a wine game (accidentally) making it go from "maximised" to "small window" it'll blackscreen the app irreversibly:

[image: screenshot of it happening]

I've tried everything to turn off this behavior I'm ok with it being system-wide but this seems to be something so deeply rooted in the ubuntu system nothing can turn it off.

How do I prevent grab-top-bar-to-minimize from happening.

I can't put the game in full screen either because fullscreen does not work for app switching. when switching back to the app the screen is frozen and no input can be made.

Answer (score 1):

Changing window sizes and switching between fullscreen and windowed mode was always troublesome with some applications inside Wine and there's no certain way to prevent that.

Some things you can try:

- Look up the application on the [Wine application database](https://appdb.winehq.org/) and look for instructions or hints dealing with that issue. Maybe there's some setting or missing DLL or different Wine version that fixes the issue.
- Play around with the display settings of the application.
- Play around with Wine's display settings, in particular the "virtual desktop" stuff.

Comment: the thing is the app no longer has any maintainers on winehq and there is no sight of it getting anyone. despite it being ever more popular on windows it seems rather abandoned on wine. i don't think this is a old issue rather an issue arrising from newer ubuntu (16.04) and wine versions (1.9.23). i've tried the virtual desktop option and despite the fact there is a seperate bar (windows 98 themed) added the grab-to-minimize still happens

Comment: You could try an older Wine version or use a virtual machine altogether (if your machine is powerful enough to run this game in it).

Comment: it is I've been trying to do hardware passtrough for a very long time but i need a mentor I can't figure it out

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw a question about that on AskUbuntu. If you can't find it you're welcome to [open a new question](/questions/ask) about it.